# assertNotEmpty("0") fails. Why is it?

Tags: php, phpunit, assertions

Doing `assertNotEmpty("0")` in phpunit fails. It should not fail because `"0"` is a string with length 1.

Following tests succeeds.

```
$this->assertEquals(1, strlen("0"));
$this->assertInternalType('string', "0");
```

Then , why it says that `"0"` is empty? Does the assert statement internally convert it to integer to check for emptiness?

Comment: What? Please add few word to explain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```